# Python, importing modules and submodules, no parent package

Tags: python, module, python-import, importerror

I have been searching/fighting for hours on something trivial as importing a class from parent to submodule with no luck what's so ever.. Basically, I am learning how to write tests in Python and so I wanted to create a Linked List and write some tests for it. The project structure is very simple:

```
SLList (Project Directory) 
   |- src
        __init__.py
        sllist.py
        dummy.py
        |- tests
             __init__.py
             test_sllist.py
   |- main.py
```

From my understanding the __init__.py file within the modules transforms it into a package. In my main.py file I have no problem calling

```
from src.sllist import Node
print(Node(5).data)
```

However this package.module notation breaks apart when I go further into the structure of the package. Let's say I want to call "sllist.py" from dummy.py, which is on the same level as sllist. It makes sense to call

```
from sllist import Node
```

But, I am following this tutorial and if you notice the pay/payments.py file, the individual is still utilizing the src.sllist type notation: https://github.com/ArjanCodes/2022-test-existing-code/blob/main/after/pay/payment.py . When I try to do this, VSCode tells me its valid via the autocompletion but I get a ModuleError:

```
    from src.sslist import Node
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

When I try to do src.sllist in tests/test_sllist.py I get the same ModuleNotFoundError mentioned above and when doing ..sllist import Node I get a ImportError:

```
from ..sllist import Node
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

So I am puzzled, I want to say this type of importing scheme has worked for me in the past but I am absolutely stumped as to what the issue is. I have tried searching on stack and one of the suggestions was to import os and then chdir to the project directory and import that way. This is a solution but I have also read that this is an anti-pattern for real world development since it is static to your machine and not universal. Could someone let me know where my understanding is going wrong?

Comment: I prefer using the full path for imports like "from src.sllist import Node" in every file you want to access the "Node", but execute every script from the root directory, then u had not problem that a modul cant be imported.